# Why Flashdata value gets null on redirecting to another function in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-flashdata

I am trying to get the input values from the view to controller and saving this value as flashdata to use it in the other controller. Now the i am able to store the value until i redirect, but as soon as it comes to redirect, it loses its value. I am not sure whats going over here.

- Do I need to see my config again? If yes, then what I need to see?
- My both the functions are rights but if I am missing anything?

Here is my code below:-

**Controller.php**

```
public function first() { 
 $testing = $this->input->post('fname');
 $this->session->set_flashdata('fstname', $testing);
 $this->session->keep_flashdata('fstname');
 // echo $this->session->flashdata('fstname'); //able to get the flashdata value till here. 
 redirect('Home/second/'); //but when I am using this, flashdata loses its value
}

public function second() { 
 $data['getfname'] = $this->session->flashdata('fstname');
 $this->load->view('details', $data);
}
```

**View (details.php)**

```
 <?php echo $getfname ?>
```

***Output***

Null

**config.php**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files'; 
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session'; 
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200; 
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/sessions/'; 
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE; 
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300; 
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

**autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries']=array();
```

Additionally, I also tried using userdata() but its not showing on the second function after redirect.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: yes, I have tried few possibibilities, but nothing work. I wil try again

Comment: @KirkBeard i tried again, but still it didnt work

Comment: first step to debugging, and this will be incredibly helpful throughout your coding pursuits. put `print_r`'s everywhere. first see if the post variable isn't null. then after that printr the session and see if it is there (comment out redirect for this). if it is... well then you have an issue with your session system. I've seen this type of issue with sessions getting destroyed after redirect with no known cause. I can't explain it, and AFAIK those questions were never answered. Best I can offer in that situation is a clean install of everything.

Comment: I have print_r  in my codes. I just didnt copy here so that my code looks simple and easy to understand. Anyways, this is how I came to know about the value is Null

Comment: my post variable values are not null while in the first function. I echoed the session before redirecting to another function as shown in the code above. But when I am using the redirect to second funcgtion, its value are null. And I found by using print_r and var_dump.

Comment: @Alex so u recommend to reinstall codeigniter again?

Comment: You aren't the first, just google "php losing session on redirect codeigniter". And like I've said, I've seen this type of question more than a few times in the past months here. I've personally experienced it but it was isolated to a particular server and was directly related with ajax calls but the problem eventually resolved itself when I upgraded to 3.1.9. Prior, I spent a whole day debugging: tried every known config, nothing changed but the site worked fine on another server so I was frustrated. You could indeed try a fresh XAMPP install/CI install.

Comment: But first try to see if regular session variables stick after redirect. Also verify you are autoloading the session library and that you have specified the session cookie name and save path.

Comment: @Alex I am using `$this->load->library('session')` in the controller under the `__Construct`. AndI am not too sure how to use the autoloading session, neither I am sure how to use the session cookies and path.

Comment: I have left my setings basic and default

Comment: autoload.php -> add `session` to array. check ci docs if still confused. more info on the rest of the items in the `config.php` file under `sess_`

Comment: can you share Session and cookie definitions in you config.php ?

Comment: @BRjava I have updated my code. These are my basic settings in the config.php and autoload.php

Comment: could you try  $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;

Comment: @BRjava I tried with Null just now, and its same. Var_dump output is Null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210489/session-data-lost-after-redirect-in-codeigniter-3-1-2 --  can you go through these steps ?

Comment: @BRjava I tried those steps mentioned, however I am not able to get the flashdata from one function to another after redirect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter "flashdata" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307705/codeigniter-flashdata-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

#### First:

check if Post data is not empty

```
$testing = $this->input->post('fname');
var_dump($testing);
exit;
```

#### Second:

you can skip keep_flashdata, you dont need that in that context

#### Third:

Check session setting in `config.php` for example:

```
$config['sess_driver']          = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name']        = 'mysession';
$config['sess_expiration']         = 86400;
$config['sess_save_path']          = 'sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']           = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']     = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

check `autload.php`:
`$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', [...]);`

#### Fourth:

check session flash var directly:

```
$strFstname = $this->session->flashdata('fstname');
die($strFstname);
```

Your code should work, I used flashdata like this many times.

Comment: @Bjoerm I am able to get the post values from the form (as mentioned in the first step). When I am assigning the flashdata just before the redirecting and checking its value, I am still getting the value. But as soon as after the redirect to the other function in the same controller.php file, it value gets null. I have also updated my autoload.php and config.php files as you shown here, its still not working

Comment: and also I have removed the `keep_flashdata` from the controller. but no luck!

Comment: My output Value (for first step) using var_dump($testing) : string(5) ''David'';

Comment: I assume that there is a redirect before directing to 'home/second'. How are your routes managed? Maybe the system direct to the core controller and then to the home controller, then the flashdata is lost.